# Error: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: spring-boot

When I tried to send a GET request I am getting JSON response as below:

[{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"1001","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"1001","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"User1001","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":"USD","recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"B","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"1002","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"1002","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"User1002","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":"USD","recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"C","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"1003","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"1003","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"User1003","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":"USD","recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"P","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"1004","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"1004","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"User1004","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":"USD","recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"O","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"1033","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"1000","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"User1000","leadContact":true,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":"USD","recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"A","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"5604","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":"FTES","id":"230633","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"manglayaan.usr","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":null,"recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"Q","responsibleParty":false,"state":"PENDING"},{"accountId":"1000","applicationNumber":null,"bankNumber":null,"contactDetails":null,"contactId":"23060","customerInfoReferenceNumber":null,"externalSystemId":null,"id":"SAjnW8lduCcvzlRVHEjB","lastUpdatedTime":null,"lastUpdatedUser":"SYSTEM","leadContact":false,"loanInformation":null,"orphanFlag":"N","preferredCurrency":null,"recoveryAccountingStatus":null,"relationshipType":"A","responsibleParty":true,"state":"PENDING"}]

My code is:

```
@Component
public class TokenizationFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    List<String> sensitiveFields = Arrays.asList("accountId", "govt_id");

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    ContentCachingResponseWrapper readWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpResponse);
    HttpServletResponseWrapper writeWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResponse);

    chain.doFilter(request, readWrapper);

    String content =
        new String(readWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(), readWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());

    System.out.println("Content: " + content);

    try {

      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
      //JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(content);

      sensitiveFields.forEach(field -> {
        if (jsonObject.has(field)) {
          try {
            Object tokenId = jsonObject.opt(field);
            String maskedData = tokenizationServiceForMaskedData(tokenId.toString());
            jsonObject.put(field, maskedData);
            writeWrapper.addHeader(field + ".tokenId", tokenId.toString());
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });

      writeWrapper.getOutputStream().write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private String tokenizationServiceForMaskedData(String tokenId) {
    return "****-****-****-*****";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra "[" and "]"

**[**{"accountId":"1000"....ate":"PENDING"}**]**

json should start and end with {}
Then this will work:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
```

Or you should first read JSONArray and then read the JSONObject as an item from this Array

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);// 0 - index of the json item inside JSONArray
```